# Magento Multiple Store Template Change

Tags: magento, templates

I have two stores under one domain, which is the full site the other is mobile site, I set different templates to them. But for some reason, the mobile site still uses the full site template. I doubled checked database, and the templates have been correctly set.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated different themes for different store.
Go to **System->configuration->design** 
and then chose your package (from Current Configuration Scope) and add different themes for both packages